# Parameter passed into API request to Nest app gets converted into an object somehow

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-firestore, nestjs, ngxs

I was having trouble querying data from my database receiving an internal server error for something that should work.  I couldn't find any problems in my own code so I looked at the `main.js` file generated when I run `npm run build` on the app.  I started `console.log()`ing things in that file just to see what was being passed along which is when I discovered NestJS is receiving an object from the API request.

Here's how everything flows.

Inside a function in my component I dispatch an action to my NGXS state passing in a `string`.

```
this.store.dispatch(new SetCurrentProductList(this.NavData.dataId));
```

Inside my state I have an action for handling the dispatch which looks like this

```
//imported into state for action
export class GetSingleNavList{
    static readonly type = '[ProductNavIndexState] fetched a category';
    constructor(public category: string){}
}

//inside of state class
@Action(GetSingleNavList)
    getSingleNavList(ctx: StateContext<ProductIndexModel>, {category}: GetSingleNavList){

        return this.dataService.fetchSingleProductIndex(category).pipe(tap(result =>{
            const newCategoryList: ProductIndexStoreItem[] = [];

            ctx.getState().categories.forEach(a =>{
                if(a.category !== category){ newCategoryList.push(a); }
                else{
                    const modifiedCategory: ProductIndexStoreItem = {
                        category: a.category,
                        products: [...result]
                    };
                    newCategoryList.push(modifiedCategory);
                }
            });

            ctx.patchState({categories: newCategoryList});
        }));
    }
}
```

The `fetchSingleProductIndex()` function in the service file.

```
fetchSingleProductIndex(category: string): Observable<ProductIndexListItem[]>{
    const path = `${this.URL}/product-index/single-category-products?category=${category}`;

    return this.http.get(path) as Observable<ProductIndexListItem[]>;
}
```

The `@Get()` method inside of my NestJS controller looks like this

```
@Get('single-category-products')
async getSingleProductIndex(@Query() category: string): Promise<ProductIndexListItem[]>{
    return await this.dataService.getSingleProductIndex(category);
}
```

Then inside the service file for my controller I make a request from my firestore data like this.

```
public async getSingleProductIndex(category: string): Promise<ProductIndexListItem[]>{
    const data = db.collection('product_index_list').doc(category).collection('products');
    const demo: ProductIndexListItem[] = [];

    return await data.get().then(result => {
        const dataList: ProductIndexListItem[] = [];

        result.forEach(a => { dataList.push(a.data()) });
        return dataList;
    }).catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

This is where I initially started getting an error.  Inside the terminal I got this message

> Value for argument "documentPath" is not a valid resource path. Path must be a non-empty string.

This is referring to the `.doc(category)` part which made absolutely no sense to me.

Inside the `main.js` file compiled in my `dist` folder the same function looks like this.

```
getSingleProductIndex(category) {
    return Object(tslib__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["__awaiter"])(this, void 0, void 0, function* () {
        const data = _database__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__["db"].collection('product_index_list').doc(category).collection('products');
        const demo = [];
        
        return yield data.get().then(result => {
            const dataList = [];
                
            result.forEach(a => { dataList.push(a.data()); });
            return dataList;
     }).catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

This is where I noticed there was an object being passed in by `console.log()ing` category` which returns an object that looks like this.

```
{data: 'theValueIPassIn`}
```

So when I change the `.doc()` method to `doc(category.data)` the function works as expected.  However when I make the same modification in the service file in my Nest app I get an error in VSCode reminding me that the property doesn't exist because I'm defining the argument as a `string`.

I tried `console.log()`ing inside the controller defined in the `main.js` file and saw that I get the same object there as well.  It seems it happens somewhere inside the API call between the apps but I have no clue as to why.  Can someone help shed light on this and how to correct it?

Answer (score 1):

Your URL, based on what you've got, should be something like

```
<host>/product-index/single-category-products?category=someValueHere
```

Because of how `@Query()` returns an object of all the query parameters sent in automatically. There's no need to try to use something like `data.category` in the url, just need `category`

Comment: The error you're getting has nothing to do with the query parameters and instead has to do with your database query. `db.collection().where().collection` is not a function. Wherever you're going that, you should take a look at what it's doing.